# I need to know how to exec two commands on the same var with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

class Janela:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('800x480-3+0')
        self.start = Button(text="Start", font="minecraftia 18", bg="grey", command=self.menu)
        self.start.place(x=364, y=290)
    def menu(self):
        jan1 = Tk()
        self.bt1 =Button(jan1, text = "next", command=self.jans)
        self.bt1.place(x=200, y=200)
        jan1.geometry("800x480-3+0")
    def jans(self):
        jan2 = Tk()
        self.bt2 =Button(jan2, text="back", command=jan2.destroy, command=jan1.destroy)
        self.bt2.place(x=200, y=200)
        jan2.geometry("800x480-3+0")


root = Tk()
Janela(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: For one, you should never create more than one instance of `Tk`. If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple solution will be to create a `function_A` that calls **2 functions or methods**. And then bind that function to the Tkinter button.

`def function_A(func1, func2):
    func_1() # or method
    func_2() # or method`

So in your function

```
def jans(self):
    jan2 = Tk()
    def double_command():
        jan2.destroy()
        jan1.destroy()
    self.bt2 =Button(jan2, text="back", command=double_command)
    self.bt2.place(x=200, y=200)
    jan2.geometry("800x480-3+0")
```

and in Tkinter button you can 
`self.bt2 =Button(jan2, text="back", command=double_command)`

Comment: NameError: name 'function_A' is not defined
Still show that problem @Vineeth

Comment: And Gabriel you cannot destory jan1 from `jans` function as `jan1` is not in the local scope of the `jans` function.

Comment: And I have updated the answer.( before i forgot to rename the function_a to double_command) It should work now but still as mentioned you cannot delete jan1 from the below function. And hope this helps you understand how to run 2 or more commands at once.

Comment: No No, It's okay. Let me know if you have any problem :)

Comment: How could i closed it, if i cannot do what i'm trying?

Comment: Okay tell me what you are trying

Comment: So, i'm on engineer college, and that's my project for this year, it's a software for children with 4 activies. One of them it's to show the picture of an animal , and his name in english (We are all Brasilians) and the kid has to answer it right. If he answers it wrong, he gets to try again until he answered right, and there is the problem. When he answers right we want the software to go back and change de options, so the kid can start the "test" again. And we thought to close the two windows, so he would get to the menu again, but we cannot do that.

Comment: If you have discord or whatsapp, could you text it to me?